# could not found @ReactModule annotation in com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RnGestureHandleModule

Tags: react-native

when i run

```
react-native run-android
```

the app can run,but i got this error:"could not found @ReactModule annotation in com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RnGestureHandleModule"
[image]

and my react-native version is 0.58.6,if you have any solution ,please contact me.thanks!